# Scheduled task to upload a file to S3 with PowerShell ignores user profile settings

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, scheduled-task

I am using Windows task scheduler with a user that has an AWS profile configuration under C:\Users<username>.aws\configuration (content below)

```
[default]
s3 =
    max_concurrent_requests = 300
    max_bandwidth = 5000MB/s


[profile BackupProfile]
s3 =
    max_concurrent_requests = 300
    max_bandwidth = 5000MB/s
```

The redacted script looks like this:

```
Set-AWSCredential -ProfileName BackupProfile 
Write-S3Object -BucketName xyausdpaisd-bkt -Region ap-south-1 -File $latest.FullName
```

When running the script manually, I get the expected speed (2Gbps) but when the same script is run with the Scheduled task (same user, as admin), the speed is around (150mbps).

Why is this scheduled task much slower when they are supposed to use the same S3 configuration?

Comment: Have you tried increasing the task priority?

Comment: I just did and it worked. Please suggest the answer and I'll mark it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can increase the priority of a task in an XML template and create a task with normal or above normal priority.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/taskschd/tasksettings-priority